Actor-partner interdependence model (APIM) with binary outcome in Mplus or R?
My data are dyadic and I'm very familiar with the APIM with continuous outcomes, but I'm not sure how to estimate this model with a dichotomous outcome. Usually I use SEM in Mplus but I can muddle through R. In Mplus, is it sufficient to use a WLSMV estimator? Should I use GEEs and, if so, how would I do that?
For reference, all my variables are observed. I am examining associations between couples' reports (continuous) at T1 and the onset of an event (dichotomous) at T2, controlling for several time-invariant sociodemographic characteristics. I have found a few articles on this topic (listed below) with examples in SAS or SPSS, but I've never used SAS and just use SPSS for data management, descriptives, and basic inferentials, not dyads.
Loeys, T., Cook, W., De Smet, O., Wietzker, A., & Buysse, A. (2014). The actor–partner interdependence model for categorical dyadic data: A user‐friendly guide to GEE. Personal Relationships, 21(2), 225–241. https://doi.org/10.1111/pere.12028
Loeys, T., & Molenberghs, G. (2013). Modeling actor and partner effects in dyadic data when outcomes are categorical. Psychological Methods, 18(2), 220–236. https://doi.org/10.1037/a0030640
Any advice would be very welcome!
